# Configuring Windows 10 Update Rings in Intune/MEM using Powershell

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I'm working on Configuring Windows 10 Update Rings in Intune/MEM.I'm able to do that from MEM but Is there any way that i can update using Powershell.?

Thanks

Couldn't find any documentation yet.

Comment: In graph its windowsUpdateForBusinessConfiguration. You can find the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-deviceconfig-windowsupdateforbusinessconfiguration?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I'm trying to achieve the steps on this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/protect/windows-10-update-rings vi PowerShell or Graph API